# Rendering routes with 2 or more route parameters with AnalogJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jamstack, analogjs

I have routes of that are defined like this:

```
  {
    path: ':category/:topic',
    component: TopicComponent,
    data: ROUTE_DATA,
    resolve: { topic: topicResolver },
    canActivate: [topicGuard]
  },
```

[The AnalogJS documentation explains how to render routes container a single parameter.](https://analogjs.org/docs/features/routing/overview).

So for a single `productid` parameter we would define a file like this:

```
products.[productId].page.ts
```

How do we define routes with 2 or more parameters?

Pseudo code would be something like this:

```
products.[productId]/[partid].page.ts
```

Thoughts?

Comment: quick thought `products.[productId].[partid].page.ts`?

Comment: @Skocdopole that works!!  Cool!!!  Do you want to list it as the official answer and I can check it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to use the dot notation to divide path segments, like this `products.[productId].[partid].page.ts`.