# Rendering dynamic routes in AnalogJS without using a prefix or a folder?

Tags: angular, typescript, jamstack, angular-scully, analogjs

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086555/rendering-routes-with-2-or-more-route-parameters-with-analogjs) we were able to render dynamic routes with 2 or more parameters, but they have to be either prefixed or contained in a folder.

I'd like to be able to render a route like this, where `:category` would be the first segment of the path, is dynamic, and it could be things like `blog`, `concept`, `example`, `task`, `formula`, etc:

```
 {
    path: ':category/:topic',
    component: TopicComponent,
    data: ROUTE_DATA,
    resolve: { topic: topicResolver },
    canActivate: [topicGuard]
  },
```

Thoughts?